# C++ stack smashing detected when returning from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, stack-smash

I have the following function, which works fine and produces the expected output, but right upon returning, it produces

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code of the function:

```
bool derive_aes_key(const unsigned char* shared_secret, int shared_secret_len, unsigned char* aes_key) {
    
    memset(aes_key, 0, AES_KEY_SIZE);

    unsigned char prk[AES_KEY_SIZE];  // PRK must be at least AES_KEY_SIZE bytes
    unsigned int prk_len = AES_KEY_SIZE;

    // Use HMAC to derive a pseudorandom key (PRK) from the shared secret
    HMAC(EVP_sha256(), shared_secret, shared_secret_len, NULL, 0, prk, &prk_len)


    // Use PRK as the AES key
    memcpy(aes_key, prk, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    
    cout << "Code reaches this statement" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

How it's called from main:

```
unsigned char aes_key[AES_KEY_SIZE];
derive_aes_key(999c3293c8ed1e8173cc9d6e84ed9476884670422517291995183336a7f9b0f6, 32, aes_key);
cout << "Code doesn't reach this statement" << endl;
```

I saw many questions about stack smashing errors, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205461/c-stack-smashing-detected-but-everything-is-working-before-return-statement), which is similar, but was not able to figure out my specific mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the post accordingly

Comment: Wanted to answer but the question was closed. The error is here: `unsigned char prk[AES_KEY_SIZE];  // PRK must be at least AES_KEY_SIZE bytes`. As for the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/HMAC.3ssl.en), *It places the result in `md` (which must have space for the output of the hash function, which is no more than `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE` bytes).* You must declare `unsigned char prk[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE]`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I thought AES_KEY_SIZE was sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
unsigned char prk[AES_KEY_SIZE];  // PRK must be at least AES_KEY_SIZE bytes
```

As for the [HMAC man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/HMAC.3ssl.en)

> It places the result in `md` (which must have space for the output of the hash function, which is no more than `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE` bytes).

You should have declared the array `unsigned char prk[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE]`.